# IE 10, document.links does not possible to access using the id of the link but only with index

Tags: javascript, html

Following code is working in FireFox 23.0.1 as well as Chrome 29 but not in the IE 10. What can be the problem ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          function loadFile1(){
              alert("loading...");
          }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="file2.html" id="link1">file 1</a>
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var arr = document.links;
         document.links['link1'].onclick = loadFile1;
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('link1').onclick = ...`

Comment: Or, maybe because when you click the anchor element, it navigates away from the page before you can see the alert.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté an alert in onclick will stop the page from navigating away until it's dismissed.

Comment: @Strelok `alert`s are DOM0 - they have no specification. It is only that every browser we know block the interpreter until an alert is dismissed, but well, we're talking about IE. That was only a supposition as I can't test on IE10 at the moment unfortunately.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté see my answer. Definetly looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug to me. `document.links` returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) , so you can use the `HTMLCollection.namedItem(name)` method to retrieve the link by name:

```
document.links.namedItem('link1').onclick = loadFile1;
```

This will work in all browsers.

Comment: Yes, the `namedItem` method ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75708506)) is the standard way to do this. Though, as the element has an id, a standard and simpler way to access it would be using `document.getElementById` imho.